# Java: Parse HTTP session

Tags: java, http

I have a recorded HTTP session (as an InputStream, can be converted to a String if needed), and I'd like to parse the HTTP protocol: find the headers, the content-type, and the body.  I can roll this by hand, but expect to get better performance and reliability if I use a standard library.  How should I do this?

Pseudocode:

```
http = new HttpParser(session);
http.resultCode; // returns 200
http.headers("Content-Type"); // Returns a string
http.body(); // Returns an input stream of the body
```

UPDATE:  The session was logged (think of tcpdump).  I have only the HTTP Response, not the HTTP Request.  But everything I want to know comes from the HTTP Response.

Comment: @jtahlborn of course - surprisingly, none of the libs shown met my needs.  Specifically, Apache's HTTP Client does _not_ seem directly capable of the above

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you were attempting to parse a pre-created stream.  the http protocol is pretty simple, there's not much to it.